Can someone help me find why my react project is not showing up inside my gh-pages link
I am trying to upload my React app from GitHub to my GitHub page but the screen remains blank when I deploy the app. I´d like to know if is there anything wrong with my code that would stop Github Pages from uploading my React App?

It seems you are using the default Jekyll build system for the GitHub pages deployment, but your project seems to be a Node.js-based project. Consider customizing the GitHub Actions workflow to build your project with Node.js/npm instead, see the documentation  on configuring GitHub pages.
